# Explicit formula for embedding Cayley graph of free group into hyperbolic space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, metric-embeddings, cayley-graphs

The problem is to embed Cayley graph of free group with $n\geq2$ generators (the same as Bethe lattice with coordination number $2n$) into any model of $\mathbb{H}^2$ (we have no model preference, the only condition is to preserve the metric structure of the graph). Any numerical algorithms like MDS are not suitable. Unfortunately, I can't find any explicit formulas. But my guess is that insofar as embedding is unique, formula must exist. I would be glad if someone help with useful papers or provide any useful reasoning.

**UPD**
Two additions: 1) embedding must be isomorphic, 2) I meant the embedding into $\mathbb{H}^n$ – I guess that for $n>2$ generators Cayley graph cannot be embedded into hyperbolic plane.

Comment: The embedding is definitely not unique. My answer (below) gives just one possibility.

Comment: "preserve the metric": you won't get any isometric embedding. Just a tripod in a tree can't be embedded isometrically into $H^2$ (or even $H^n$). Still there are bilipschitz embeddings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subgroup $\Gamma < \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ generated by the matrices
$
a = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
$
b = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$ is free of rank two.  It acts on the upper half plane model of $\mathbb{H}^2$ via Mobius transformations.  The orbit of $i$ gives the vertices of the Cayley graph; translates that differ by $a$, $b$, $a^{-1}$, or $b^{-1}$ are connected by a geodesic edge.  It is an exercise to show that this gives the desired embedding.  [Hint: build the Voronoi domain about $i$.]

---

A few remarks.

1. As YCor points out, no embedding can be isometric.
2. There are "quasi-isometric" embeddings of the Cayley graph into $\mathbb{H}^2$, but this one is not, as the generators are parabolic.
3. By taking finite index subgroups you can obtain equally nice actions of higher rank free groups on the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: (And the proof that they generate the free group is probably the canonical example of the [Ping-pong lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma). )

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I don't see if this embedding is isometric - only the isometric embeddings that are interesting for me.  For neighboring vertices, everything seems to be fine here, but are the distances to non-neighbors preserved?  This requirement led me to write about the uniqueness of the embedding.

Comment: The embedding is not isometric, and no such embedding exists.  I've added a remark to this effect.